# Controller "JMS\TranslationBundle\Controller\TranslateController" has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container

Tags: php, symfony4

I Upgade Symfony from 3.3 to 4.1 , JMS\TranslationBundle stop working.

Error is

```
Controller "JMS\TranslationBundle\Controller\TranslateController" has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to define such a service?
```

i try import

imports:
- { resource: '@JMSTranslationBundle/Resources/config/services.xml' }

without change

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I wrote comment here:

[constructor arguments and does not exist in the container](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/issues/498#issuecomment-423127012)

And this work for me:

add to service.yaml:

```
JMS\TranslationBundle\Controller\TranslateController:
    public: true
    arguments:
        $configFactory: '@jms_translation.config_factory'
        $loader: '@jms_translation.loader_manager'


JMS\TranslationBundle\Controller\ApiController:
    public: true
    arguments:
        $configFactory: '@jms_translation.config_factory'
        $updater: '@jms_translation.updater'
```

and comment or remove this:

```
#imports:
#- { resource: '@JMSTranslationBundle/Resources/config/services.xml' }
```